# Laravel - post calling completely differente route than given

Tags: php, laravel

so I have a form with POST method but it's not calling the route I am giving it, but instead calling a different one. Here is the code:

**profile.blade.php**

```
<section id="my-events" class="pdl15em">
    <div class="personal-events">
      <span class="personal-events-title personal-info-title">
        My Events:
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="personal-events-list">
      @each('partials.profile_my_events', $events, 'event')
    </div>
  </section>
```

**partials-profile_my_events**

```
<div class="specific-event black-font">
    <a href="/event/{{ $event->id }}" class="specific-event-name"> 
        {{ $event->name }} 
    </a>
    <a class="edit-pencil" href="/update_event/{{ $event->id }}"> <i class="fa fa-pencil pencil-edit" style="color:black"></i> </a> 
    <button class="delete-profile" onclick="deleteEventButton()"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o delete-bin" style="color:black"></i> </button>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('deleteEvent', $event->id) }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button type="submit" id="invisi" class="edit-pencil confirm-button">
            Confirm Delete
        </button>
     </form>
</div>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('deleteEvent/{id}', 'EventController@delete')->name('deleteEvent');
Route::post('deleteAccount/{id}', 'ProfileController@delete')->name('deleteAccount');
```

**EventController.php**

```
public function delete(Request $request, $id)
    {
      Event::destroy($id);

      return redirect('/events');
    }
```

**javascript**

```
function deleteEventButton() {
  let invisi_button = document.getElementById('invisi');
  invisi_button.style.display = 'block';
}
```

**actual HTML when loading page on browser**

```
<button class="delete-profile" onclick="deleteEventButton()"> 
   <i class="fa fa-trash-o delete-bin" style="color:black"></i> </button>
<i class="fa fa-trash-o delete-bin" style="color:black"></i>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="s9XixoRRFu2FyDtMe4pJfLwpTjxM4wGGevjHyjPC">
<button type="submit" id="invi" class="edit-pencil confirm-button">
   Confirm Delete
</button>
```

There are currently 2 problems:

1. When I click the button `<button class="delete-profile" onclick="deleteEventButton()"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o delete-bin" style="color:black"></i> </button>` it is redirecting to deleteAccount when it should just make the POST button visible.
2. When I click the POST button `<button type="submit" id="invisi" class="edit-pencil confirm-button">Confirm Delete</button>` it is also redirecting to deleteAccount instead of where it should really redirect, which is deleteEvent.

I've tried basically everything, so if you see the problem please let me know!

I shared the code I thought was necessary to fully understand my situation, though if you need any other code, please let me know and I'll provide it ASAP!

Thanks alot for your time

**Edit 2** - Added `</post>` in **partials-profile_my_events**.

Comment: with this code, it seems not possible. Can you post the complete code of your view file?

Comment: added it on the top! was that what you asked for?

Comment: BTW, you forgot to close the form ``</form>`` in the ``partials-profile_my_events`` template view file.

Comment: thanks! I fixed that but the problem persists... I noticed when loading the page, my HTML is actually different. I'll edit the post and add it for you to check it

Comment: check if your route file have another route with same name, that can cause this issue.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu, yes, quite possible.

Comment: it does not... i just checked it

Comment: I just searched through the whole project and the only time "deleteEvent" exists is in that HTML and the routes file

Comment: @GuilhermeMoreira can you please try changing `Route::post('deleteEvent/{id}', 'EventController@delete')->name('deleteEvent');` to a closer and dd something like `Route::post('deleteEvent/{id}', function(){ dd("test"); })->name('deleteEvent');` let's see if this will work.

Comment: Since you're using a loop that renders the partial you'll end up with multiple elements with the same `id` attribute - that is invalid, `id`s *must* be unique on a page

Comment: do you think that contributes to the problem I'm having, or is it just a side thing?

Comment: Either way, it's invalid. `document.getElementById('invisi')` I think will select the first element with that `id`

Comment: i already fixed it! but the problem is still there... I still have no idea why the HTML on the actual page is different from the one I'm writing

Comment: View caching? Did you run `php artisan view:clear`?